# Azure Function Targeting .NET Standard Showing Warning

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, azure-functions, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

Just installed Visual Studio 15.5 Preview so that I can create an Azure Function targeting .NET Core. Without making any changes, I'm seeing a warning -- see below -- that reads:

> Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client 5.2.2 was restored using .NET
>   Framework version 4.6.1 instead of the project target framework .NET
>   Standard version 2.0. This package may not be fully compatible with
>   your project.

Any idea how to fix this or do I ignore this warning? As I said, this is a brand new Azure Function project I created with no changes at all.

Here's what the warning looks like:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pretty much ignore it, in **this** case.

[Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client/) targets "Portable Class Library (.NETFramework 4.5, Windows 0.0, WindowsPhone 8.0, WindowsPhone 8.1, WindowsPhoneApp 8.1)" (or `net45+win8+win81` as it's the target framework moniker called), which means it's fully compatible with .NET Core and .NET Standard (>= 1.2).

The warning comes, because it do not target the `netstandard1.x` or `netstandard2.x` moniker specifically. It just tell you "this might not be compatible on .NET Core/.NET Standard".

Comment: You can get rid of the warning by setting `<NoWarn>NU1701</NoWarn>` in your .csproj.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you did nothing wrong: this is to be expected for now. Functions v2 are in beta now, so you'd have to live with this warning for a while. It should give you no functional issues.